# TIFF to KMZ passing altitude data

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, kmz, altitude

I am currently trying to create a KMZ from a GeoTIFF by using gdal_translate. This Works fine and I am accomplishing this by using by using this command

```
gdal_translate.exe -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY c:\in.tif c:\out.kmz -co FORMAT=JPEG -co ALTITUDE=50.0 (Meters) and add -co ALTITUDEMODE=absolute
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add a fixed altitude relative to the ground raster than the absolute value when brought into Google Earth.

I understand that the KML file should have the elements

```
  <altitude>2744.0</altitude>
  <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
```

but cannot seem to figure out how to incorporate this into the code.